# generate statistics hibernate not showing insert/update stats

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring+JPA+Hibernate

This is how my bean is defined

```
<bean id="entityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
<.....other properties.......... >
</bean>
```

The generate_statics is only showing statistics for select queries.

How can we see statistics for inserts?

Is there a simple configuration that can be used to show all the statistics where we can see hibernate entity to query translation time and insert/update time to db?

Answer (score 0):

I enabled the statistics using the following steps

1. Include the following dependency in your pom

   org.lazyluke
       log4jdbc-remix
       0.2.7
2. replace your driver class with net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy
3. enable the required in your log4j properties

   log4j.logger.jdbc.sqlonly=OFF
   log4j.logger.jdbc.sqltiming=INFO
   log4j.logger.jdbc.audit=OFF
   log4j.logger.jdbc.resultset=ERROR
   log4j.logger.jdbc.connection=ERROR
   log4j.logger.jdbc.resultsettable=OFF

4.Add log4jdbc to the connection url

for example: i am using oracle db. so i changed the connection url from

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(hostname:port)

jdbc:log4jdbc:oracle:thin:@(hostname:port)